# Create custom SQL Server listener to connect to shared localdb instance?

Tags: sql-server, localdb, sql-server-2017

There seems to be a huge bug in SQL LocalDB 2017 rendering ALL shared instances inaccessible from any version.

```
C:\Windows\system32>sqllocaldb create TestInstance 12.0
LocalDB instance "TestInstance" created with version 12.0.2000.8.

C:\Windows\system32>sqllocaldb share TestInstance SharedInstance
Private LocalDB instance "TestInstance" shared with the shared name: "SharedInstance".

C:\Windows\system32>sqllocaldb start TestInstance
LocalDB instance "TestInstance" started.

C:\Windows\system32>sqllocaldb info TestInstance
Name:               TestInstance
Version:            12.0.2000.8
Shared name:        SharedInstance
Owner:              TSTWCD03\lan
Auto-create:        No
State:              Running
Last start time:    01/08/2019 11:50:18
Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#SH1FE0E0\tsql\query

C:\Windows\system32>powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
PS C:\Windows\system32>
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\TestInstance;Integrated Security=true;Connect Timeout=10"
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlConnection.Open();
PS C:\Windows\system32>
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
PS C:\Windows\system32>
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlCmd.CommandText = "CREATE LOGIN[testlogin] WITH PASSWORD = 'testpass', CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF, CHECK_POLICY = OFF";
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
-1
PS C:\Windows\system32>
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlCmd.CommandText = "ALTER SERVER ROLE[sysadmin] ADD MEMBER[testlogin]";
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
-1
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlConnection.Close();
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\TestInstance;Integrated Security=false;User ID=testlogin;Password=testpass;Connect Timeout=10"
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlConnection.Open();
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlConnection.State
Open
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlConnection.Close();
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\.\SharedInstance;Integrated Security=false;User ID=testlogin;Password=testpass;Connect Timeout=10"
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlConnection.Open();
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlConnection.State
Open
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlConnection.Close();
```

I am now able to connect to my local and shared instance using a custom login.

At this point I simply execute the SqlLocalDB.msi x64/2017 while the command screen stays open.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlConnection.Open();
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlConnection.State
Open
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlConnection.Close();
PS C:\Windows\system32> sqllocaldb stop TestInstance
LocalDB instance "TestInstance" stopped.
PS C:\Windows\system32> sqllocaldb start TestInstance
LocalDB instance "TestInstance" started.
PS C:\Windows\system32> sqllocaldb info TestInstance
Name:               TestInstance
Version:            12.0.2000.8
Shared name:        SharedInstance
Owner:              TSTWCD03\lan
Auto-create:        No
State:              Running
Last start time:    01/08/2019 11:59:32
Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#2CCAB366\tsql\query
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlConnection.Open();
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"
At line:1 char:1
+ $SqlConnection.Open();
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException


PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\TestInstance;Integrated Security=true;Connect Timeout=10"
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlConnection.Open();
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlConnection.State
Open
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SqlConnection.Close();
```

So something seems to have changed when my 2014 instance starts the (localdb).\SharedInstance is no longer to be linked to my shared instance.

I wonder.. is there a way to register my own sql server listener? When I could create an extra listener like (MyOwnDB)\MyInstance and point it to the shared instance..  this would not be overwritten by the 2017 installation.

Documenation seems limited. Can anyone help?

Comment: Does unsharing and re-sharing help? Also, do you have an actual need for all of this to keep working *during* an installation, or is it just about fixing things up afterwards? The former comfortably falls under "scenarios that were probably not tested and are very low on anyone's priority list to get working".

Comment: Actually -- does just re-opening the connection in a new window work, never mind explicitly unsharing and re-sharing things? The named pipe instances will not survive a server restart, and while `SqlConnection` and the pool *should* pick up on that, I can imagine this won't necessarily work smoothly in all circumstances, never mind when an installer has run.

Comment: No. The only remedy I have found is to remove v2017.

Comment: However, I did manage to pinpoint the issue to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\LocalDB\Binn\SqlUserInstance.dll. When I overwrite this from C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\LocalDB\Binn\SqlUserInstance.dll things seem to work fine.

Comment: Looks like you might be running into [this bug](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/36481279-sql-server-2017-express-localdb-shared-instance-co), then. No suggested solution yet. (Copying over the 2014 version might "fix" things, but I suspect you might run into other issues when you start actually using 2017 instances -- presumably there were changes made for other good reasons.)